# Debug php in NetBeans

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, backend, lamp

i just want to debug php code in netbeans to know how to do it, i have already installed the google chrome netbeans extension, but when i try to debug my code, a window says:

"netbeans connector chrome extension is required
To run your project in Chrome with NetBeans Connector, you must first install the NetBeans Connector extension in the Chrome Web Store."

also, i have my project opened in my localhost and of course i can see the netbeans icon in the corner of the chrome page.
can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

my OS is ubuntu 18.04
and my stack is xampp (lampp)

Answer (score 1):

A way to debug php in Netbeans (without chrome extension):

1. Apache server running
2. PHP configured
3. Install php-xdebug
4. Add in your php.ini:

   zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/... path to .../xdebug.so

   xdebug.remote_enable = 1

   xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp

   xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1

   xdebug.remote_mode = req

   xdebug.remote_port = 9005

In Netbeans go to Tools > Options > PHP

Tab General

- Write your path to PHP interpreter

Tab Debugging

- Debugger port: 9000
- Session ID: netbeans-xdebug